# Exclusão de arquivo com fs não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Tenho um `if` para excluir um arquivo, porém ele não está sendo excluído e nem está lançando erros.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

```
if (results[0].photo != `arquivos/imgpadrao.jpg`) {
  fs.unlink(`./public/${results[0].photo}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando um método assíncrono ([`fs.unlink`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)), que espera um *callback* para quando for resolvido. Desse modo, você deve usar uma função de *callback* para saber se houveram erros:

```js
if (results[0].photo !== `arquivos/imgpadrao.jpg`) {
  fs.unlink(`./public/${results[0].photo}`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Houve algum erro!', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Tudo certo! Arquivo removido.');
    }
  });
}
```

Você também pode utilizar a versão síncrona desse método, [`fs.unlinkSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path), realizando a tratativa de erro com um `try`/`catch`:

```js
if (results[0].photo !== `arquivos/imgpadrao.jpg`) {
  try {
    fs.unlinkSync(`./public/${results[0].photo}`);
    console.log('Tudo certo!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Houve algum erro!', err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `unlinkSync` para excluir:

```
fs.unlinkSync(`./public/${results[0].photo}`);
```

Ou utlize a Promise 
`` fs.unlink(`./public/${results[0].photo}`).then(res => {}).catch(err => {}) ``

Comment: Acho que vale ressaltar na resposta que a versão que utiliza as promessas não é exportada diretamente por `require('fs')`, mas sim `require('fs').promises`, e em versões posteriores do Node.